# Create Strings using Template Literals using forEach Method

Tags: javascript, foreach, template-literals

Can someone help me please fix my code? I was using forEach method in this exercise

I think I’m close but it’s still giving me undefined, it’s already inside the result.failure because I checked by adding another string/num.

```
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak",],
  skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
};
function makeList(arr) {
  // Only change code below this line
  const failureItems = [];

  const results = arr.forEach(k => failureItems.push(`<li class="text-warning">${arr[k]}</li>`));


  // Only change code above this line

  return failureItems;
}

const failuresList = makeList(result.failure);
console.log(failuresList);
```

it should be resulted to this

```
[
  '<li class="text-warning">no-var</li>',
  '<li class="text-warning">var-on-top</li>',
  '<li class="text-warning">linebreak</li>'
]
```

but in this code my result is this

```
[ '<li class="text-warning">undefined</li>',
  '<li class="text-warning">undefined</li>',
  '<li class="text-warning">undefined</li>' ]
```

Comment: `k` refers to the value not the index. So `${k}` is enough. Also why not use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Comment: NB: `forEach` always returns `undefined` - not useful to store in a variable `result` which you don't use either.

Comment: I was just trying if this exercise can be solve using forEach method. I used  `${arr[k]}` to access the value of `result.failure` to print in the console.

Comment: does it mean I can't use forEach to solve this?

Comment: Of course you can, just don't assign its undefined return value to anything since it's of no use anyway... and as mentioned, you need `${k}` and not `${arr[k]}`. `forEach` (just like `for ... of`) will loop over _values_, not indices. If you wanted indices (which is unnecessarily complicated) you would use `.forEach((_, k) => ...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to concatenate `k`. Also as mentioned in the comments, [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined`.

To fix the above:

```
arr.forEach(k => failureItems.push(`<li class="text-warning">${k}</li>`));
```

Another solution using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
function makeList(arr) {
  return arr.map(k => `<li class="text-warning">${k}</li>`);
}

const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak",],
  skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
};

const failuresList = makeList(result.failure);

console.log(failuresList);
```

Comment: yes I saw this solution using map method I was trying if it is possible using forEach

Comment: @pichimnc Please look at the answer again. It shows the `forEach` solution too, just as several people already pointed out in the comments on your quesiton above!

Comment: Omg! it works!!! I was wrecking my brain for this yesterday. Thank you for all the help!!!! 